# Beautiful Soup HTML Not Matching 'View Page Source' in Browser

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape a web page using bs4, however, the HTML doesn't seem to match what I can see when using the 'view page source' in Chrome. As a novice in this area, any guidance on this would be much appreciated! Details below:

An example of a target web page [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/m/63c37511-b114-3718-a601-7e898a22439e/a-big-tech-encore-and-twitter.html) and the code used is shown below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/m/63c37511-b114-3718-a601-7e898a22439e/a-big-tech-encore-and-twitter.html'
response = requests.get(my_url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(doc))
```

When viewing the page source in my browser (Chrome), the snippet below is included in the html:

```
"siteAttribute":"ticker=\"GOOGL;AAPL;PYPL;TWTR\"
```

However, when looking at the file output from the code above, the `siteAttribute` has changed and no longer has the same information. Instead, it shows:

```
"siteAttribute":"wiki_topics=\"Big_Tech;Apple_Inc.;Facebook;
```

After researching online I can't figure out what is causing the discrepancy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually,What  data items do you wnat to scrape from this url?

Comment: @F.Hoque Just the tickers from the `"siteAttribute":"ticker=\"GOOGL;AAPL;PYPL;TWTR\"` snippet that appears in the HTML when viewing page source.

Comment: That's  inside js function and bs4 can't grab it

Comment: Ah, thank you, happy to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on inspect from pop up box tab of chrome devtools then press  ctrl + F and paste `siteAttribute":"ticker=\"GOOGL;AAPL;PYPL;TWTR\` then you will see that the desired result is under a script tag. Please see the screenshot from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X64K7.png)

Comment: Thanks, after doing some further research I have a follow up - why is it that beautiful soup will return the rest of what is in the `<script type="text/javascript">` tag but not that little snippet?

Comment: BeautifulSoup can pull only the pure html portion but dynamically populated by JavScript portion of the html tree can't rendered by bs4 meaning can't see. Thanks

Comment: Have you any suggestions on ways of accessing these dynamically populated portions through Python?

Comment: That's a bit complex  but you  do that  applying API, re or selenium

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll check those out